# Supercritical and subcritical Hopf bifurcation

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

While studying the bifurcations for two dimensional dynamic systems, I came across the subcritical and supercritical Hopf bifurcation. I know that the subcriticâl involves a limit cycle around a stable equilibrium and the supercritical one around an unstable equilibrium. But is there an easier way to recognize which one of the two Hopf bifurcations there is? E.g. by looking at the eigenvalues?

Comment: Just eigenvalues are not enough, you need to know and calculate some quantities depending on the higher order derivatives, see in [Scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation#First_Lyapunov_Coefficient).

Comment: @Evgeny You could also check Poincare map, right? See if it has a fixed point away from the SS, and check the Floquet multipliers.

Comment: @tsbertalan You are right, but usually (from analytical viewpoint) this information is much harder to get than checking Lyapunov values. To some extent Lyapunov values tell you information about the two most important Floquet multipliers, which correspond to a restriction on the center manifold at Hopf bifurcation point.